# Can someone help me delete Google cloud Search Index using Java

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, gcloud-java

Can someone help me delete Google cloud Search Index using Java or a sample script

Comment: show us your attempts so far.

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/training/fts_intro/lesson2#indexes) AppEngine indexes cannot be deleted

> You can't currently delete indexes, though you can delete documents from them

Comment: thanks...i tried deleting the documents but was trying to delete indexes. Hope delete option comes along soon.